# Grape directory structure(uninitialized constant error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-grape, grape-api

When I try to run the server I get uninitialized constant DasBoot::API::V1 (NameError) error. RubyMine recognizes path, and doesn't raise any error. I have tried everything in my power, read the docs, but without success.

```
Project tree:
├── app
│   ├── api
│   │   └── dasboot
│   │       ├── api
│   │       │   ├── v1
│   │       │   │   └── standings.rb
│   │       │   └── v1.rb
│   │       ├── api.rb
│   │       └── grape.rb
```

app/api/dasboot/api.rb

```
require_relative 'grape'

module DasBoot
  class API < Grape::API
    mount DasBoot::API::V1
  end
end
```

app/api/dasboot/api/v1.rb

```
class DasBoot::API::V1 < Grape::API
  version 'v1', using: :path, vendor: 'DasBoot'

  desc 'For testing API connection'
  get :hello do
    { message: 'Hello, sailor!' }
  end

  mount Standings
end
```

Standings endpoint

app/api/dasboot/api/v1/standings.rb

```
class DasBoot::API::V1::Standings < Grape::API

  resource :standings do
    desc 'Fetch Standings'

    get '' do
      "#{ Time.now }"
    end
  end
end
```

routes.rb

```
...
mount DasBoot::API => '/api'
...
```

application.rb

```
...
    config.paths.add File.join('app', 'api'), glob: File.join('**', '*.rb')
    config.autoload_paths += Dir[Rails.root.join('app', 'api', '*')]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an inconsistency in the naming of your `DasBoot` module and the `dasboot` directory.

In Rails, we use CamelCase for modules and classes naming as a convention. If Rails encounters a constant it doesn't know of, it uses the `underscore` method on the constant name and tries to find the corresponding snake_case directory for this constant. In your example, the expected directory containing your "DasBoot" module should then be named:

```
"DasBoot".underscore
=> "das_boot"
```

So, the `DasBoot` module is expected to be located in a `das_boot/` directory. But according to the directory structure you give us, your `DasBoot` module is located in a `dasboot` directory instead (without the `_` in the middle), which is why Rails doesn't manage to load it correctly.

If you fix this (either by renaming your module to `Dasboot` or the directory to `das_boot`), it should all work fine.